# Twitter bootstrap RC2 and jquery select 2 unexpected margins and paddings

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I recently started to use `bootstrap RC2` and `jquery select2`, but if I use it with `bootstrap form-control` class I get unexpected margins and looks weird.

[image]

Could someone please  give me a hint on this?

html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-6 sepereate-group">
    <select name="gender" id="gender" data-placeholder="Select gender" class="form-control select2">
        <option></option>
        <option value="1">Male</option>
        <option value="2">Female</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-6 sepereate-group">
    <select name="gender" id="gender" data-placeholder="Select experience" class="form-control select2" >
        <option></option>
        <option value="1">No experience</option>
        <option value="2">Some experience</option>
        <option value="3">Experienced</option>
        <option value="4">Very experienced</option>
    </select>
    /div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay solved, removed the `form-group` class from the select tag and 
and defined select2 this way

```
 $(".select2").select2({ width: '100%' });
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and found [this](http://fk.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/index.html) library. Works like expected!